# javascript . copying an image from one canvas to another and saving the image from the new one works unreliably

Tags: javascript, canvas, download, resize

I have a canvas with an image.
I want to download its image when a link is clicked, but at a different size.

My solution works only when I press the link every other time. so I press the link the first time and it doesn't work (web browser's image saver fails to open), second time it does work, third time it does save but if the canvas image has been modified since the first successful save (second attempt), this attempt saves the original unmodified version, forth time it does work (modifications to canvas image is included in the saved image). This pattern is consistent and I don't believe I am mismanaging my files.

```
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var canvasN = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctxN = canvasN.getContext("2d");

    canvasN.width = canvasX.value; // canvasX/Y global variables
    canvasN.height = canvasY.value;

    var imgo = new Image();
    imgo.src = canvas.toDataURL(); // data from original canvas global variable
            imgo.onload = function() {
        ctxN.drawImage(imgo,0,0, canvasN.width,canvasN.height);
        link.href = canvasN.toDataURL("image/png");
    };
        link.download = "image.png";


    });
```

upon a link being clicked, my code creates a new canvas, with my desired size.
it then loads the data from the original canvas into an image, which is then drawn onto the new canvas, and its image is then finally downloaded (not reliably however).

How do I fix this to make it work consistently?

Comment: Try moving `onload` before `imgo.src = canvas.toDataURL();` maybe it happens too fast

Comment: @Konrad after trying I've found moving the entire `onload` function before `imgo.src = canvas.toDataURL();`  causes the exact same behavior. moving just the single line before causes the function to never run.

Comment: You don't need the intermediary `<img>`, draw directly your `canvas` over `ctxN` (`ctxN.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvasN.width, canvasN.height)`), and you should avoid `canvas.toDataURL()` which may produce a string to long for the `<a href>`, instead call `canvasN.toBlob(blob =>  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob))`.